# Pandas Filter for string value

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, filter

I have a dataframe with multiple dates. (2021-04-20, 2021-04-21, etc.)
I want to filter it on a specific date. (2021-04-21)

This is my code:

```py
def select_by_date(df: pd.DataFrame, date: str = None):
    if date:
        log.info(f"Using data from {date}")
        df["datum"] = pd.to_datetime(df['datum'])
        return df.loc[(df["datum"] == date)]
    else:
        log.warn(f"No date provided")
        return input_sendungen
```

This is the dataframe before (`pd.to_datetime`):
[image]

Dtype (Object):
[image]

This is the dataframe after (`pd.to_datetime`):

[image]

Dtype of the column is (`df.info()`):

[image]

Why is the returned dataframe empty?

Comment: `date` is a string, so not equal to any `datetime`? Another question: Why do you convert the `datum` column to `datatime` (`df["datum"] = pd.to_datetime(df['datum'])`) when it already is `datetime` according to the screenshot?

Comment: I've tried both. Date as string and date as datetime. Did not work either. The screenshot was taken after the conversion

Comment: I doubt the `datum` column contains dates: In the screenshot there's a non-zero time part (the `22` after the `T`)?

Comment: I added screenshots to the question, so you can see how the column looked before and after

Comment: As noted in the last comment: It looks to me that you don't have dates, there's a non-zero time part? Could you add a [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)) that replicates your problem? Otherwise it's hard to diagnose what's going wrong.